# Import from Folder data source missing from PowerPivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

If I look around on the Internet, I see people have the ability to import all files from a given folder:

http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/importing-data-from-multiple-log-files-using-data-explorer/
[image]

Whereas I can't:

[image]

I'm running `Excel 2013` with the `PowerPivot` add-in enabled and `SP1` installed.

[image]

**Does anybody know where the option to import from folder has gone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to install the Power Query Excel add-on (mentioned in the Blog post you linked).

So, go [grab Power Query from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39379) and install it.

This will add a new Excel tab named "*Power Query*", which will have it's own "*Get External Data*" section on the ribbon (similar to the *Data* tab).  That button/drop-down contains the wanted "From Folder" button.

[image: Excel with Power Query]

Comment: Thanks a lot (I should spend more time to read). Any other Excel add-ons worth installing in your opinion?